# Opening a link after a lookup check

Tags: vba, hyperlink, lookup, offset

I have code that looks like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim searchFolder As String, fileName As String

    Static PowerPointApp As Object

    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

        With Application
            Msg = .IfError(.VLookup(Target.Text, Worksheets("Test").Columns("A:B"), 2, 0), "")
            If Msg <> "" Then MsgBox Target.Value & vbLf & vbLf & Msg, vbInformation, "Suggestion d'inspection"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

It checks a cell's content from Col A in Sheet 1 against a list from Sheet 2, Col 1; if there's a match, then a MsgBox will give info from the resulting cell's offset value from Col 2.

I'm trying to adapt this into another function that would do the same check, but then instead of displaying a message from the offset cell, it would open an hyperlink from that same cell.

As an example:
I put "Info X" in A:1 Sheet1; it checks in Col A Sheet 2 and if it has a match in A45 it will open the link from B45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the returned value from the vlookup is not equal to "". If not, then pass that value into the first argument of `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink`.

Edit:
Remove the two lines about `msg` and replace them with:

```
hlink = .VLookup(Target.Text, Worksheets("Test").Columns("A:B"), 2, 0)

If hlink <> "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (hlink)
End If
```

You may need to declare hlink as a string variable.

Comment: Like I just edited in my original post, I'm quite the newb in VBA. Lots of trials and errors... Which means that as it is, I'm not sure how to translate your suggestion into code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm now =) 
Still learning, but I believe I'm getting the hang of it now...

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please consider marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Done =) I quickly upvoted your comment last night, but I forgot the check ^^'